# Combine multiple styled elements with styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I know that we can extend or add styling to existing components with styled-components like the `Link` component of `react-router-dom`. The said feature is indicated [here](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components). But, my problem is, how can I combine two or more existing components then add some more styles?

In my case, I have a reusable component for text elements like `span`, `p` and `a` with standard font-size, font-weight, etc. At the same time, I want to use the react-router-dom's Link component. Currently, I have something like this:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { TextElement } from '../common';

/*
Can I do something like this?
const MyLink = styled(Link, TextElement)`
    margin: 10px 0;
`;

or this?
const MyLink = styled([Link, TextElement])`
    margin: 10px 0;
`;
*/

const MyPage = props => (
   <>
       <MyLink to="/next-page" />
   </>
);
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

### EDIT

My `TextElement` component is just something like this:

```
const Element = styled.span`
   font-size: 13px;
   font-weight: 500;
`;

// These styles are sample only. Actual styles depend on a "variant" prop.
// I did not show it here since it doesn't have to do with the question I'm asking.

export default ({ tag }) => (<Element as={tag} />);
```

Comment: can you show how your TextElement looks like ?

Comment: I edited my question to show TextElement @CodeManiac

Comment: You can't mix two components like this mate, what you can do is you can take the common css inside a variable  and than use that variable wherever you want that css

Comment: Maybe just nest them? `MyLink = ({ children, ...props}) => <Link {...props}><TextElement>{children}</TextElement></Link>`

Answer (score 29):

You can use mixin for this using css helper.
Let's say you put the code for `TextElement` in a `spaced` mixin like:

```
import { css } from 'styled-components';

const spaced = css`
  margin: 10px 0;
`;
```

And another mixin for `Link`

```
const styledLink = css`
  color: blue;
`;
```

Then you can define your `MyLink` as:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const MyLink = styled(Link)`
  ${spaced}
  ${styledLink}
`;
```

Answer (score -1):

The style component could be the wrapper of your custom component. For example:

```
Your style component:

export const CustomSpanWrapper = styled.div`
    span {
        ...your-styles
    }
`;

Your other component:

<CustomSpanWrapper>
    <CustomSpan>
</CustomSpanWrapper>
```